# Can you convert a mut i8 into an i32?

Tags: unix, casting, rust, pty

I am attempting to build a small terminal emulator and am running into some interesting type conflicts with libc. When I am attempting to set up the slave portion of the pty connection I need to create the slave with a system call to ptsname() in order to get the name for the pts so I can access it. However, I get a type error saying that libc::ptsname() requires an i32 for the input. This is in direct conflict with the man page that says it should be passed a file descriptor. I'm just wondering if I can convert the libc::c_int that I have for a file descriptor into a i32 to pass into ptsname.

The code is as follows :

```
use libc::{self, c_int, grantpt, posix_openpt, ptsname, unlockpt, O_RDWR};
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
use std::process::{Child, Command, Stdio};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Pty {
    process: Child,
    fd: i32,
}

fn create_pty(process: &str) -> Pty {
    let master: c_int;
    unsafe {
        // create master/slave pair of fd
        master = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
        if master == -1 {
            panic!("Failed to posix_openpt");
        }

        // set slave ownership and mode as master
        let mut result = grantpt(master);
        if result == -1 {
            panic!("Failed to grantpt");
        }
        // unlock slave
        result = unlockpt(master);
        if result == -1 {
            panic!("Failed to unlockpt");
        }
    }
    let slave: c_int = ptsname(master as i32);
    slave = libc::open(slave);

    let mut builder = Command::new(process);

    match builder.spawn() {
        Ok(process) => {
            let pty = Pty {
                process,
                fd: master,
            };

            pty
        }
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("Failed to create pty: {}", e);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let shell = "/bin/bish";

    let pty = create_pty(shell);
    println!("{:?}", pty);
}
```

and the console output(The second error can be ignored for now):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:42:24
   |
42 |     let slave: c_int = ptsname(master as i32);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected i32, found *-ptr
   |
   = note: expected type `i32`
              found type `*mut i8`

error[E0060]: this function takes at least 2 parameters but 1 parameter was supplied
  --> src/main.rs:43:13
   |
43 |     slave = libc::open(slave);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected at least 2 parameters

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0060, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0060`.
error: could not compile `experiment`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not saying that it requires an *input* of `i32`, but rather that you're asking that `ptsname(master as i32);` has the type `i32`. This might be a bit confusing because `c_int` is an alias for `i32`, so it sounds like it's asking for an unrelated type.

The problem is that you're giving `slave` the type `c_int`, when `ptsname` returns `*mut c_char` (`c_char` is also an alias, this time for `i8`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was mistaken in the return type of ptsname.